# What type of programming is needed to run an IOS app

Tags: php, mysql, ios, iphone, sql

So there are websites that use dynamic web pages and use PHP for this. Also websites need to use SQL to run information in their server databases.

How would an iOS app do this? Through the same type of programming (PHP&SQL)?

I'm a student only looking to learn. Thanks!

Comment: Try Googling "create ios app" and you will find some helpful information.

Comment: Native iOS apps are written in Objective-C. Core Data can be used to provide a persistent data hierarchy (usually over SQLite). Now, go search :)

Comment: @DOK I mean its more of creating apps that rely on server. Couldn't anyone google any stack question if they pleased?.. Instead I asked it on here so I could gain useful and personal responses.

Comment: IOS app? if native application Objective C should be used this is Apple's default programming language for IOS....

Comment: Mnramos92 asking questions to get personal responses is good idea but be a bit more specific as to what you are after and put yourself forward as someone who has done some research, that is what @DOK was trying to get to, I think. Let me know if I can be of any more help.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Getting%20Started

And once you have had a look around in the above link, have a read of this https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/

Lastly if you want to really go creative and social check out the iOS SDK for Facebook and start making cool apps - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-sdk-tutorial/